# How to turn off Wi-Fi 15min after it had been turned on?

Tags: tasker, automation

I seek help creating a Tasker profile/task to turn off the Wi-Fi 15min after it had been turned on.

Is this possible in Tasker?

Comment: I am not familiar with Tasker , in [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)  it is Trigger : WiFi state change> connected, Action: wait 15 minutes, WiFi configure > disable WiFi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Tasker , in [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) another versatile automation app:

**Trigger :** WiFi state change → connected (choose network)

**Actions:**

1. Wait 15 minutes
2. WiFi configure → disable Wi

**Constraints:** None (Run always) or set up your Constraints under which macro runs