# keep needing to reset wifi

Tags: wi-fi, networking

The network at my office works when I first connect to it, but every few minutes it becomes very slow. When this happens, I need to quickly turn the Wifi off and on, then it gets fast again. As you can expect, this gets really annoying.

Is there anything I can do on the phone side to help with this? Maybe it can automatically reset the wifi connection every few minutes? That would be ideal. Or any idea on what I can ask of our IT guy? I mentioned it to him, and he sort of blew me off.

I am using a Moto z4 with the current Android OS

Comment: There are automation apps like Automate. Have you tried using those?

Comment: @WrichikBasu I haven't. That is a good idea though. Thanks

Comment: Helpful for you https://android.stackexchange.com/a/169593/131553. You just need to add another action (3) Enable wifi and save the macro